# Total value contains part of current value in highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

how can I do something with my columns value in highcharts? I have two values: "total" and "current". Total is always bigger becouse it contains current value. I write some example in js Fiddle:
[link to example](http://jsfiddle.net/stz7btw6/1/)

```
 series: [{
    name: 'John Total',
    data: [8, 9, 4, 7, 6],
    stack: 'male'
}, {
    name: 'John Current',
    data: [3, 4, 3, 2, 5],
    stack: 'male'
}, {
    name: 'Jane Total',
    data: [8, 5, 9, 8, 9],
    stack: 'female'
}, {
    name: 'Jane Current',
    data: [1, 0, 4, 4, 3],
    stack: 'female'
}]
```

I want to dislplay chart where total value is a maxiumm value of column and current column as a part of total column. In my example in first column of "John Total" should be 8 and have part of "John Current" which is 3. In my code example values is summed and finish value is 11. How can I fix that and got columns like in picture?
This series have maxium values:

```
series: [{
    name: 'John Total',
    data: [8, 9, 4, 7, 6],
},
```

And this series have results as a part of total. How many points John get from Total:

```
{
    name: 'John Current',
    data: [3, 4, 3, 2, 5],
    stack: 'male'
},
```

So first column should have max value 8 and include 3 like in picture. Blue column on picture should have 8 becouse we have this in first array and black column should to have 3. How can I acheive this when I have got Maxium value and part of this value In one column?
[image]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I expect my columns have maxium value of 'John Total', and 'Jane Total' and contains 'John Current' stack for 'John Total', and 'Jane Current' stack for 'Jane Total'. So first column for example wiill have 8 and contain 3. Now for first column value is as if summed up total with current and have 11. I need have max 8 and contain 3 in its lower section

Comment: I have just my total and part. My total should be showed as max value I dont need to sum both but just show total and a part of total in one column

Comment: just look at first column in my exaple there is all ok but in diagram should have maximum value 8 (from John total) not 11

Comment: Do you want to sum the data array of same gender?

Comment: No I want only display maximum value from first array and part of second array as a part of total column like in my example

Comment: In my series for first column john have total 8 but current is 3 and Excatly this I want to display in chart, I dont want to sum values becouse Total value is assumed and contain value form current

Comment: Basically, you want to the bar to be represented by the total value, individually composed of each user.

Comment: @LukeKov do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/31f222uv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: img]

As per your comment

> How can I acheive this when I have got Maxium value and part of this value In one column?

In this case you cannot use

`stacking: 'normal'`

You have to use overlapping column charts

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false,
      groupPadding: 0.4 //added padding to give some spacing between column
    }, 
  },
```

And series with

```
series:[{y: 8,x: 0.20 }, {y: 5,x: 1.20}, { y: 9,x: 2.20}, {y: 8,x: 3.20 }, {y: 9,x: 4.20}, ]},...];
```

here x value represents the position of the column(if you don't define x in series, column will overlap each other)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],

  },

  yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Number of fruits'
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false,
      groupPadding: 0.4

    },

  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Jane Total',

    data: [{
      y: 8,
      x: 0.20
    }, {
      y: 5,
      x: 1.20
    }, {
      y: 9,
      x: 2.20
    }, {
      y: 8,
      x: 3.20
    }, {
      y: 9,
      x: 4.20
    }, ]
  }, {
    name: 'Jane Current',

    data: [{
      y: 1,
      x: 0.20
    }, {
      y: 0,
      x: 1.20
    }, {
      y: 4,
      x: 2.20
    }, {
      y: 4,
      x: 3.20
    }, {
      y: 3,
      x: 4.20
    }, ]
  }, {
    name: 'John Total',
    data: [8, 9, 4, 7, 6],
  }, {
    name: 'John Current',
    data: [3, 4, 3, 2, 5],
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Update** as per OP

> I want to deliver array with values under variable to data: and I want fill only Y axis without writing {y:array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZSb4.png)}, {y:array[2](http://jsfiddle.net/d0epbLkh/)} for every value in array

For this you can use array map function to update array of object

```
$scoe=new Object();
$scoe.johnTotal = [7,8,9];
$scoe.janeTotal = [7,8,9];
$scoe.janeTotal=$scoe.janeTotal.map((el,i)=>{
    el={y:el,x: i+0.20};
  return el;
})
$scoe.johnCurrent = [2,5,6];
$scoe.janeCurrent = [3,4,6];
$scoe.janeCurrent=$scoe.janeCurrent.map((el,i)=>{
    el={y:el,x: i+0.20};
  return el;
})
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0epbLkh/) demo

Comment: Yes i think it is it! Thanks You man. Could You tell me how can I make up my Y axis from series. I have $scope..myData = array [1,2,3,4]. How Can I put my array to series.data Y axis?

Comment: add you angularjs fiddle sample  . What is you actual problem? Are you facing problem in creating data like `[{y: 8,x: 0.20 }, {y: 5,x: 1.20}, { y: 9,x: 2.20}, {y: 8,x: 3.20 }, {y: 9,x: 4.20}, ]`

Comment: Yes i know it is good and work fine. I just want to know it is possible to deliver array with values to data:. And this values throw only to Y like in Your example. I dont want to prepare my $scope..myData = array [1,2,3,4] LIKE $scope..myData = array [y:1,y:2,y:3,y:4]. I just want to deliver array as data:$scope.myData and I want to find options like fillOnlyTheYAxis with my values from array

Comment: by _fillOnlyTheYAxis with my values from array_ you want to have yAxis labels 1,2,3,4 instead of 0,2,4,6,8 current values

Comment: I want to deliver array with values under variable to data: and I want fill only Y axis without writing {y:array[1]}, {y:array[2]} for every value in array

Comment: or something like  data: [{y:$scope.myArray}] how could I do that?

Comment: Thanks for help, have a nice day :)

Comment: but can You tell me how Can i resolve this? I want to have two columns per category with deliver array of values like in this example I havent idea how can I achieve situation from Your example: http://jsfiddle.net/31f222uv/2/

Comment: check this updated one http://jsfiddle.net/d0epbLkh/ . There is huge understanding gap form me ;-)

Comment: Thanks for help :)